# Proof that an infinite set can be written as the countably infinite union of pairwise disjoint infinite subsets without using the axiom of choice.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have the following theorem

Any infinite set can be written as the countably infinite union of pairwise disjoint infinite subsets

I have found a couple of proofs for this but I was wondering if there is some proof that doesn't use the axiom of choice (and it's equivalent statements).
Does there exist such a proof?

Comment: It is easy to construct such a partition explcitely for $\Bbb N$, say. Now if only you could prove that for your infinite set $A$, there exists an injective map $\Bbb N\to A$ ...

Comment: @Hagen that would require choice, though.

Answer (score 4):

No. An [amorphous set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set) is infinite but cannot be written even as the union of two disjoint infinite sets, and it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ without choice that amorphous sets exist.